Add modifiers automatically on new objects
With thew new blender 4.1 release, I've started wondering if there is a way to add modifiers automatically for new objects.
For example. If I add a new sphere, I want it to come with the new autosmooth modifier and with weighted normals modifier. Those two modifiers I use on every single object I work, so it would be nice if I could have them set automatically.
Is it possible?

yes it should be possible using a python script
